# How can i solve "loading error module" for Prettier?

Tags: vite, prettier

I tried adding Prettier to a random project to get familiar with the setup but after I installed the plugin I can't seem to get past this error, and I searched for hours.

[(photo) prettier error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXUei.png)

i use: Vite - Vue & Yarn

i tried:

1. updating the path in settings.json after running `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks base`

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "prettier.prettierPath": "./.yarn/sdks/prettier/index.cjs",
}
```

or

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "prettier.prettierPath": ".yarn/sdks/prettier/index.cjs",
}
```

2. Changing the Prettier Path in VSCode settings with `C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier` or `\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier`
3. Changing the path in settings.json as in section `2.`
4. `npm install --save-dev prettier`

I guess there is a path issue or something? Any help is appreciated